# Class method to recursively remove keys from array

Tags: php, arrays, class, recursion, phpunit

I'm trying to write a simple class to remove unwanted keys from arrays recursively. Nothing special.

```
<?php
class RemoveUnwantedKeysFromArrayRecursively {

    public function remove(array &$array, $keys)
    {
        $keys = (is_array($keys)) ? $keys : array($keys);

        foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
            if(in_array($key, $keys, true)){
                unset($array[$key]);
            }

            if (is_array($value)) {
                $this->remove($value, $key);
            }
        }

        return $array;
    }
}
```

But while I unit test this simple method, I got an error with nested arrays that remains always the same.

```
class RemoveUnwantedKeysFromArrayRecursivelyTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testRemove()
    {
        $remove = new RemoveUnwantedKeysFromArrayRecursively();

        $arrayTest = array('key1' => 'test', 'key2' => 'test2');
        $arrayKeys = array('key2');

        $remove->remove($arrayTest, $arrayKeys);
        $this->assertTrue(array_key_exists('key1', $arrayTest), 'test if key1 is present');
        $this->assertFalse(array_key_exists('key2', $arrayTest), 'test if key2 is present');

        $nestedArrayTest = array('key1' => 'test', 'key2' => 'test2', 'key3' => array(
        'key1' => 'nested key1', 'key2' => 'nested key2')
    );

        $remove->remove($nestedArrayTest, $arrayKeys);
        $this->assertTrue(array_key_exists('key1', $nestedArrayTest['key3']), 'test if key1 is present in the nested array');
        $this->assertFalse(array_key_exists('key2', $nestedArrayTest['key3']), 'test if key2 is present in the nested array');
    }
}
```

> test if key2 is present in the nested array. Failed asserting that true is false.

What I'm doing wrong? My question is similar to [PHP Recursively unset array keys if match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708860/php-recursively-unset-array-keys-if-match) and [PHP recursive search and replace array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074119/php-recursive-search-and-replace-array-elements?rq=1) but I have read their answers without luck.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shold pass all the `$keys` rather than just one `$key` when calling your function recursively here:

`$this->remove($value, $key);`

Also note that the `$key` in this context comes from the original array, not the one with all the keys to be removed.